# How can I test for a player at a given x and z but at any height?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to test for if a player is at a certain x and z, but not a certain height, and I can't find anything that says how to do it.
Here's what I have:

```
/testfor @a[x=-50,z=79,r=1]
```

The problem is, it's only true if the player is standing on the command block, and I need it to be true if the player is anywhere directly above the command block, like five blocks above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by using the cubic volume selectors (`dx`,`dy`,`dz`) rather than a radius.

For example, to test for players around (`-50`, `79`) with any height (or rather, a height from -5000 to 5000):

```
/testfor @a[x=-51,dx=2,z=78,dz=2,y=-5000,dy=10000]
```

This tests for anyone with x from `-51` (x) to `-49` (x + dx), a z from `78` (z) to `80` (z + dz), and y from `-5000` (y) to `5000` (y + dy)

Comment: This will not work because `y` is still going to default to the sender's position (the command block), while `dy` will default to 0. The player will still have to be at the same height as the command block.

Comment: @Skylinerw My bad, only tested the command in chat. Should be (kind of) fixed now, but your command is the better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Unspecified origin parameters will default to the sender's location, being the command block. You can change the origin to be that of the player so that the `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters default to their position instead of the command block.

```
/execute @a 50 ~ 79 /testfor @a[c=1,r=1]
```

Comment: A note to OP that this will [count the same player multiple times](https://gfycat.com/ShyUnluckyAsiaticgreaterfreshwaterclam) if other players are on the same y level, so be careful using this for output signal strength or commands other than `/testfor` (shouldn't matter if your commands are only for use on singleplayer, though).